# Get python file's path from outside Directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory, path

**I want to get absolute directory path of python file, not current working Directory.**

Suppose I have `app.py` in `'/home/user/coding/python/'` directory.

Code of `app.py` is:

```py
# app.py
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

- I have been in `'/home/user/coding/python/'` directory I ran `python app.py` and got

```
/home/user/coding/python/
```

- Now I changed dir `cd` to `/home/user/` and ran `python '/home/user/coding/python/app.py'` and got

```
/home/user
```

- But I want the python script to print while running `python '/home/user/coding/python/app.py'`

```
/home/user/coding/python/
```

with python command which means the directory of that python file.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#app.py
import os

print(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

will print

`/home/user/coding/python`.

If you require the separator at the end:

```
#app.py
import os

print(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))) + os.path.sep)
```

will print

`/home/user/coding/python/`.

Comment: My problem got solved from your solution.

Comment: Glad to hear @Shezan.